# Calculation of integral including exponentials

Tags: integration, analysis

So I have this integral \begin{equation} \int_1^{\infty}...\int_1^{\infty} \frac{ e^{min\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n,c\}}}{e^{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}} dx_1dx_2...dx_n \end{equation} where $c>1$. I thought that what I can do is break the integrals sequentially from 1 to $c$ and to $c$ to $\infty$. However that would require a lot of work. What I was wondering if there is a simple way to use the symmetry of the integrant to calculate the integral. What I was thinking is assuming an arbitrary ordering and thus changing the boundaries of the integrals. Anyone have any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Go with your first instinct, assume an order for $x_n$ and multply your result by $n!$ to account for this.

To deal with the min function, you only need to break up the integral for $x_1$ assumed to be the smallest.
This inner integral will be ...

$$\int _1^c dx_1 + \int_c^{x_2}e^{-x_1} dx_1 = (c-1) + e^{-c}-e^{-x_2}   $$

So $$I= n! \int_1^\infty \int_1^{x_n} ... \int_1^{x_3} 
\left ( c-1+e^c-e^{-x_2} \right ) e^{-(x_1+x_2+...+x_n)} 
  dx_2 ... dx_{n-1} dx_n  $$